# How do I get the value of the selectedSegmentIndex on to another viewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I have a PopUpViewController that pops up when the button is pressed in the main ViewController.  I have a speedDisplay (UILabel) on three different ViewControllers that I want to be able to switch the output between MPH and KMH and I cannot figure out how to do that.  I have a segmentControl in the PopUpViewController that I am trying to implement to make this happen.  Can anyone help me out here?

```
import UIKit

public enum Speed {
case KMH
case MPH
}
protocol PopUpViewControllerDelegate: class {

func selectedSpeedType(_ type: Speed)
}

class PopUpViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

weak var delegate: PopUpViewControllerDelegate?


@IBOutlet weak var altitudeSegment: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var tempSegment: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var speedSC: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var settingsView: UIView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)

    settingsView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    settingsView.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    doneButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    doneButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    let items = ["MPH", "KMH"]
    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl.init(items: items)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0        
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(speedChoice(_sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(segmentedControl)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func speedChoice(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    let index = sender.selectedSegmentIndex

    switch index {
    case 0:
        // Needs to euqal MPH to use on speedDisplay in another viewController
    case 1:
        // Needs to euqal KMH to use on speedDisplay in another viewController
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Here is the func that I have on the ViewController for speed:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getCurrentDateTime()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        locationManager.headingFilter = 5
    }
     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    map.mapType = MKMapType.standard
    let location = locations[0]
    let myLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myLocation, span: span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true

    let speed = location.speed
    if speed < 2 {
        self.speedDisplay.text = "0.0"
    }
    else {
        if speedType == .MPH {
            self.speedDisplay.text = String(format: "%.1f", speed * 2.236936284, "MPH")
            speedTypeLabel.text = "MPH"
        }
        else {
            self.speedDisplay.text = String(format: "%.1f", speed * 3.6, "KMH")
            speedTypeLabel.text = "KMH"
        }
    }
extension ViewController: PopUpViewControllerDelegate {
    func selectedSpeedType(_ type: Speed) {
        speedType = type
    }
}
```

And the code for the PopUp:

```
@IBAction func showPopup(_ sender: Any) {

    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
    self.addChild(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)

    }

}
```

I have the following for saving the segmentedController:  I believe that I am missing something because every time I select a segment it goes back to the segment 0.  It prints out like it is working but it is not saving the selection.  Any ideas?

```
@IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Comment: How you are showing the PopUpViewController from the ViewController ? Share the code please

Comment: I added it to the code above.  It pops up when I press a button that is located on the first ViewController of the app.  I have a total of three views, plus the popup view.

Comment: I mean, Share the View Controller code where you are presenting PopUpViewController

Comment: Unrelated but never use `(sender as AnyObject).state` if the type of the sender is known and static. Use `func onClkPanGesture(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)` and then simply `sender.state == .began`, in this case even better a `switch` statement.

Comment: sorry about that.  I realized that I posted that code twice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `delegate` mechanism to send data back from one ViewController to another.

Inside `PopUpViewController`

```
import UIKit

public enum Speed {
    case KMPH
    case MPH
}
protocol PopUpViewControllerDelegate: class {

    func selectedSpeedType(_ type: Speed)
}

class PopUpViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    weak var delegate: PopUpViewControllerDelegate?

    //This is global variable (internal protection level) and can be get/set from outside of the class.
    var speedType = Speed.KMPH //New line

    @IBOutlet weak var altitudeSegment: UISegmentedControl!

    ......
    ......

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        .......

        //We can select the segment control with corresponding value even popover is removed from the ViewController.
        altitudeSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = speedType.hashValue //New line
    }

    @IBAction func speedChoice(_ sender: Any) {

        let segmentControl = sender as! UISegmentedControl
        if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            delegate?.selectedSpeedType(.KMPH)
        } else {
            delegate?.selectedSpeedType(.MPH)
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `YourViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var speedType: Speed! = .KMPH
    var popOverVC: PopUpViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        popVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
        popVC.delegate = self
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        .....

        self.speedDisplay.text = "\(String(format: "%.1f", speed * 2.236936284)) \((speedType == .KMPH) ? "KMPH" : "MPH")"
    }

    @IBAction func showPopup(_ sender: Any) {

        self.addChild(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        //Assign the speedType to selected value back in PopOverViewController, and update the segmentControl to new value.
        popOverVC.speedType = speedType //New line
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}

extension ViewController: PopUpViewControllerDelegate {

    func selectedSpeedType(_ type: Speed) {

        speedType = type
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good.  I'm just getting three errors on the speedDisplay.text line.  Error 1 - Cannot assign to value: binary operator returns immutable value, Error 2 - Expected ',' separator Insert ',' and Error 3 - Expected expression in list of expressions.

Comment: Sorry about that. Updated the answer, please check once. Wrongly mentioned speed and ternary operator. **speed** changed **speedType**

Comment: I am still getting one error on the speedDisplay line - Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context.  I think I need to differentiate between MPH and KMPH form meters per second.

Comment: Check the answer now

Comment: Thanks for the help Sateesh.  I have to work on this some more later. But you've definitely got me going in the right direction.

Comment: Sateesh - I think I am pretty close to getting this completed, but I'm having an issue with the segmentController saving what I selected.

Comment: The iVar **speedType** in **ViewController** always stores whatever the value is selected by **altitudeSegmentControl**. So is there anything needs to save for us?

Comment: When I select case 1 in the segment control it automatically goes back case 0?

Comment: Hey @B.Deaton, sorry for the late reply. Actually, I've seen your message in the morning (according to India which is GMT + 5.30). I updated the code by commenting lines with 'New Line' tag. Please have a look...!!! If you are practicing the things in iOS, it would be better to have a GitHub repo so that we can run your code in our machines, flawlessly.

Comment: I've changed a few things up since the above question.  I'm trying to use a popup view controller to change the preferences of the user on two different view controllers.